# Modal de Bootstrap no se abre

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Buenas, he buscado posibles soluciones pero con ellas no consigo solucionar el problema.

intento abrir una ventana modal con Bootstrap pero esa no se abre al presionar el botón.

```
<form class="form-inline">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Login</button>

                <!--modal -->
                <!-- Modal -->
                    <div id="login" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                      <div class="modal-dialog">

                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                    </div>

                <!--modal -->
                <script>
               $("#login").dialog({
                  modal: true,
                  buttons: {
                    Ok: function() {
                      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                  }
                });
              </script>

                <button type="subtmit" class="btn btn-success">Registrarse</button>
        </form>
```

Ya he probado a poner la llamada a jquery antes que el js de bootstrap

```
<script serc="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Pero tampoco funciona de esa manera

Comment: has comprobado que no tienes errores en la consola del navegador?

Answer (score 2):

El detalle esta en como llamas al modal, sustituí `.dialog` por `.modal` de tu `script`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">    

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-THPy051/pYDQGanwU6poAc/hOdQxjnOEXzbT+OuUAFqNqFjL+4IGLBgCJC3ZOShY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form class="form-inline">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Login</button>

                <!--modal -->
                <!-- Modal -->
                    <div id="login" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                      <div class="modal-dialog">

                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                    </div>

                <!--modal -->
                <script>
               $("#login").modal({
              modal: true,
              buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                  $( this ).modal( "close" );
                }
              }
            });
              </script>

                <button type="subtmit" class="btn btn-success">Registrarse</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

La función `Dialog` es propia de `Jquery-ui`.

Bootstrap utiliza: `modal();` Intenta con `$('#login').modal('show');`

Answer (score 0):

No estás importando JQuery, tienes *serc* en vez de *src* cambia esto:

```
<script serc="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

a esto:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

y lo de

```
$("#login").modal({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
            $( this ).modal( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

es de [jquery-ui](https://jqueryui.com/), no lo necesitas.

Answer (score -1):

prueba con esto

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
          Launch demo modal
        </button>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                ...
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

```
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [answer]. Las respuestas de sólo código, si bien pueden aportar una solución a la pregunta, son mucho mejor recibidas si se acompañan de una ***explicación de la solución*** para que todos puedan entenderla.